# Will the sustained value be gone off after the criteria met again in workflow rule?

Tags: workflow, field-update

I have a field A(picklist which contains Yes,No) and B(Date which will get updated to TODAY when A is Yes or No). I have a workflow for this. And i have another workflow in which the B will be made empty if A is null.

If i create a record and the A value is none , B will be empty(as expected). If i change the value of A to Yes or No , B will get updated as TODAT date(as expected). But when i change it again to None, the B value is still there. It is not going off.

My question is , will the updated value will not be gone of even when the criteria met ? Is there any way (except through  coding) to make the B value empty after the change ?

thanks in advance !!

Comment: Can you include the actual workflow rules you're using?  This doesn't sounds right.  How are you determining if filed A is cleared?  Are you using the `A blank value (null)` value in the field update to clear field B?

Comment: WF for updation:-  Account: A EQUALSYes,No ---> Account: B TODAY()               
WF for empty :-  
Account : A EQUALS null ---> Account B null

Comment: That is really hard to understand.  Can you post some screenshots of both the workflow rules, and the field updates?

Answer (score 0):

You will need either two workflows / field updates or one process builder with two evaluations:

**First Workflow / PB Criteria**

"On Insert/update"

You field criteria should be:

```
FieldA != null then set FieldB = TODAY()
```

**First Workflow / PB Criteria**

"On Insert/update"

You field criteria should be:

```
FieldA = null/blank then set FieldB = null
```

Comment: i have used two wokflows as mentioned in my prev commnet but still the issue is coming

Comment: until you post what you are using not much we can do but guess. screenshots work